# Confusion about IO and do notation

Tags: haskell, io, monads

I'm a beginner in Haskell and confused about this code I wrote

```
readRecords :: String -> [Either String Record]
readRecords path = do
    f <- B.readFile path
    map parseLogLine (C8.lines f)
```

But it gives me this error:

```
Main.hs:15:10:
    Couldn't match type `IO' with `[]'
    Expected type: [C8.ByteString]
      Actual type: IO C8.ByteString
    In the return type of a call of `B.readFile'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: f <- B.readFile path
    In the expression:
      do { f <- B.readFile path;
           map parseLogLine (C8.lines f) }
```

`parseLogLine`'s type signature is `parseLogLine :: B8.ByteString -> Either String Record`.

I'm completely surprised. `B.readFile path` should return `IO ByteString` and so `f` should be `ByteString`. `C8.lines f` should return `[ByteString]` and map should `return [Either String Record]`.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a starting point, `readRecords` is defined with the wrong type. If the `do` block is to work in the `IO` monad, then it will produce an `IO` value, but you've defined it as returning `[Either String Record]` which is in the `[]` monad. That means that you can't call `B.readFile` which returns `IO` without triggering the type error you got.

Once you fix that, you'll find that the `map` expression on the last line of the do block has the wrong type because it produces `[Either String Record]` when it should produce `IO [Either String Record]`. Wrap the call in `return` to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed return type to `IO [...]` and used return at last statement as you said. Will accept your answer 9 minutes later.